# React <Typeahead> get selected array object id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I have an array

```
lookuplist = [
  { name: "Dave", id: 4780127, capital: "Montgomery", region: "South" },
  { name: "Jessie", id: 710249, capital: "Juneau", region: "West" },
  { name: "Steven", id: 6392307, capital: "Phoenix", region: "West" },
];
```

I am using Typeahead in a form

```
<FormGroup>
  <label className="form-control-label" htmlFor="input-email">
    Account
  </label>
  <Typeahead
    id="input-account"
    onChange={setSelected}
    options={lookuplist}
    placeholder="Choose a Account..."
    selected={selected}
    filterBy={["name"]}
    labelKey={(lookuplist) => `${lookuplist.name} (${lookuplist.id})`}
  />
</FormGroup>
```

All the functionalities of typeahead are working good,
The value set in type ahead is `name (id)` which is a **label key**, What I need is only `id` of the selected option.

For example, If I select "Dave" the typeahead **value=4780127** which is an "id" of the array.So that i can get the "id" of an array value
[image]

code:https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-sound-pzse0?file=/src/App.js

Thanks in advance.

Comment: explain problem is better

Comment: what's library for Typeahead or FormGroup?please add implement function `setSelected` and `selected`.

Comment: if add sample code in codesandbox is better for dubug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I understand what your problem is, you want to save the selected id to state instead of the entire object right?

You could try the following, so add a function handling the change:

```
const handleChange = value => {
    setSelected(value[0].id)
};
```

And then pass on the handleChange to the onChange prop and for the selected prop you filter the lookuplist based on the saved id:

```
<FormGroup>
  <label className="form-control-label" htmlFor="input-email">
    Account
  </label>
  <Typeahead
    id="input-account"
    onChange={handleChange}
    options={lookuplist}
    placeholder="Choose a Account..."
    selected={lookuplist.filter(x => x.id === selected)}
    filterBy={["name"]}
    labelKey={(lookuplist) => `${lookuplist.name} (${lookuplist.id})`}
  />
</FormGroup>
```

Comment: How to set the default value for the above ?

Comment: @RaghulRamkish What do you mean? If you mean the default useState value I would just set it to useState(null).